# How to avoid the MaxOpenPreparedStatements Exception?

Tags: java, jdbc

In my code I am using 4 prepared statements to (select,insert,update) my tables also I have to use these statements inside a for loop because I need to process large amount of data,
I am using only one db connection and the statements opened only once before the for loop and I am using the addBatch() in each iteration and after the end of loop the statements execute with executeBatch() and statements closed in the finally block , but still the MaxOpenPreparedStatements exception thrown after second iteration !!! , What can I do to avoid that ?

```
try{
     pStat1 = conn.prepareStatement("insert into...");
     pStat2 = conn.prepareStatement("update...");
     pStat3 =  conn.prepareStatement("insert into...");
     pStat4 = conn.prepareStatement("update...");


     for (.....) {
          //set parameters
          pStat1.addBatch();
          //set parameters
          pStat2.addBatch();
          //set parameters
          pStat3.addBatch();
          //set parameters
          pStat4.addBatch();

          }      
            pStat1.executeBatch();
            pStat2.executeBatch();
            pStat3.executeBatch();
            pStat4.executeBatch();
          } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }finally {
                 if(pStat1!= null){
                       try {
                              pStat1.close();
                       } catch (SQLException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                 }
                 if(pStat2!= null){
                       try {
                              pStat2.close();
                       } catch (SQLException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                 }

                 if(pStat3!= null){
                       try {
                              pStat3.close();
                       } catch (SQLException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                 }

                 if(pStat4!= null){
                       try {
                              pStat4.close();
                       } catch (SQLException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will solve the problem.But may be.Try this once

```
        pStat1.executeBatch();
          //close pStat1 here
        pStat2.executeBatch();
          //close pStat2 here
        pStat3.executeBatch();
          //close pStat3 here
        pStat4.executeBatch();
          //close pStat4 here
```

Comment: thanks , but this won't solve it because the exception thrown before reach the end of loop (second iteration) , do you mean to close the statements inside the for loop?

Comment: try to avoid that for loop

Answer (score 0):

Unroll it into four loops and process each PreparedStatement completely from preparation to closure before starting on the next one.

If you can. If the statements are interdependent you're just going to have to change that.